# File commander for Android with 2panes?

Tags: android, file-management

I have an Android tablet running Android11.

I'm looking for a good-looking and usable file commander, preferrably with 2panes, for easy file moving operations between two directories.

Features I need:

- direct option to *unmount* my USB devices, as I need to copy files from one USB to another one and best performance can be achieved if I don't have to go to storage for unmounting my USB devices, but the file commander can do that for me.
- Transferring speed and estimated time left information during file copy/move operation

Comment: USB unmount requires a rooted device.

Comment: Hm. Are you sure? Do you have any reference for it? Because it can be done from the settings, although settings app might have root access.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508736/unmount-sdcard-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Maybe take a look at [Ghost Commander](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghostsq.commander)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FX File Explorer is a great file manager. I've been using it personally for 10 years. It has split-panes which definitely come in handy as I've always used Galaxy Note devices. It has all the features mentioned.

Comment: No worries. Like I said I've been using it for ages and it's never let me down. In fact I used it heaps today, moving files to Google Drive

Answer (score 1):

[Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) sounds like exactly what you're looking for.
Completely free and ad-free on Android.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't look that great, thus it doesn't show the transfer speed and time left.

Comment: Oh, thus it doesn't provide the "unmount" option :D

Comment: the unmount part in android is a system operation - you will usually have a notification that gives you that option

Comment: I know of only 2 other dual-pane options for android, but I have not tested them for ages: [mixplorer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-2-2-mixplorer-v6-x-released-fully-featured-file-manager.1523691/) and [Ghost Commander](https://sites.google.com/site/ghostcommander1/)

Comment: Unmount: yes, but if you plug 2 USBs, only the last one will be displayed on the notification bar :( So you have to navigate yourself deep down into system settings/Battery and device care/Storage/more option/advanced and there you'll have the unmount option for both USBs.

Comment: what a unique situation. I see why this isn't so straight forward, with Android being phone centric, and only having a single USB port. I assume you're using some sort of HUB or maybe running on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I'm using a nice little USB hub, which let me join 2 USB parallel. HW is a standard phone :)

Comment: Just a thought (I have not tested this), have you tried Tasker or Automate? Maybe you can build your own USB eject notification control.